# SQL update for a certain attribute, joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I am trying to learn update which starts with...

**UPDATE** which is where you want the update to be made (TABLE)

**SET** which is the attribute to be updated

**WHERE** on which row you are making the update

My question is I want to update a state on an attributes for all the customers THAT start with a certain value on their zip code which is store in another table called address.

so far, I have this

```
UPDATE customer
Set active = false
WHERE postal_code LIKE "99%"
INNER JOIN address ON customer_id=address.address.id
```

So I have two tables where one keep all the information of the customer and another that keeps all the information of their addresses and the relation in between them is address.id, but I am stuck because I cannot make the JOIN to identify which addresses start with that value to update the attribute 'active' to false.

HELP PLEASE

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.

Comment: You are almost there, try harder

Comment: This isn't valid syntax for MySQL

Comment: Please provide a description of the schema for the two tables `customer` and `address`. I think you are actually trying to update the 'Active' field on the `address` table and _NOT_ the `customer` table.

Comment: When joining two (or more) tables it's a good habit to qualify all of the column names with the table names. e.g. `UPDATE customer INNER JOIN address ON customer.customer_id = address.customer_id SET customer.active = false WHERE address.postal_code LIKE '99%'`

Answer (score 1):

To start this journey, *IGNORE* the update for now, can you write a *SELECT* statement that returns the rows that you want to alter?

> Your initial attempt might be flawed because you joined the *Primary Key* of the address table to the PK of the customer table, unless your schema has these two tables with a 1:1 relationship, then it is more likely that the *Foreign Key* is a different column and it is the FK that you must use to join on. In your case this might be something like *Customer_Id*

Try to produce the records, with a query like:

```
SELECT Customer.Id as [CustomerId], Customer.Active, Address.Id as [AddressId]
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Address ON Address.Customer_Id = Customer.Id
WHERE Address.postal_code LIKE '99%'
```

Check the rows that are returned, the `UPDATE` will affect all these rows...

Once you have verified that the fields you *want* to affect can be returned, *then* we can convert this into an *UPDATE*

***...assuming the previous SQL statement is correct**...*

```
UPDATE Customer
SET Active = 1
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Address ON Address.Customer_Id = Customer.Id
WHERE Address.postal_code LIKE '99%'
```

Notice that the `FROM`, `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses are all still the same, we just replaced the `SELECT` clause with the `UPDATE` & `SET`.

It is even a good habit to get into first previewing your expected change by executing a `SELECT` First.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables look like(because you didnt tell us):

Example:
customer(customer_id, adress_id);

adress(adress_id, postal_cod_id);

postal_code(postal_cod_id, postal_code, active);

I thinking you want to do a UPDATE with join tables:

```
UPDATE SET T1.active = false
from
postal_code T1 INNER JOIN
adress T2 on T2.postal_code_id = T1.postal_cod_id INNER JOIN
customer T3 on T3.adress_id = T2.adress_id
WHERE
T1.posta_cod LIKE '99%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE c
 Set c.active = false
  FROM customer c
  INNER JOIN address a ON c.addressId=a.id
 WHERE a.postal_code LIKE "99%"
```